# JOLT : Need to split array and combine with other details

Tags: java, arrays, json, jolt

I am trying to JSON transformation using JOLT. 
But I am stuck at point where I have split JSON array and append other details
As seen in current output I was able to extract 0th value and append details but how can I extract next element and append offerId.

Input JSON

```
{
  "count": 100,
  "data": [
    {
      "offerDetails": {
        "offerId": "1234"
      },
      "merchantDetails": {
        "merchantName": "merchantName",
        "merchantLocations": [
          {
            "merchantAddress": "merchantAddress1"
          },
          {
            "merchantAddress": "merchantAddress2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the SPEC I have tried

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "offerDetails": {
            "offerId": "offerId"
          },
          "merchantDetails": {
            "merchantLocations": {
              "0": {
                "merchantAddress": "merchant.name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
      }
]
```

Current Output

```
{
  "offerId" : "1234",
  "merchant" : {
    "name" : "merchantAddress1"
  }
}
```

### Desired Output

```
[{
        "offerId": "1234",
        "merchant": {
            "name": "merchantAddress1"
        }
    },
    {
        "offerId": "1234",
        "merchant": {
            "name": "merchantAddress2"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help,

Traverse the `merchantLocations` for merchant name and shift backwards from `merchantLocations` till `offerId`

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "merchantDetails": {
            "merchantLocations": {
              "*": {
                "@(3,offerDetails.offerId)": "[].offerId",
                "merchantAddress": "[&1].merchant.name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```